# Best way to split string in valid HTML with maximum part length

Tags: php, html, split, mpdf

I have the following problem:

- I am preparing HTML code to be appended finally in mPDF library
- I generate a big chunk of HTML and CSS code, which partially exceeds my defined PCRE_BACKTRACK_LIMIT (100'000 characters)
- I want to split my HTML code which is very long into chunks with a maximum length of 100'000, but they have to end with a closing HTML tag

As of now, I have cut the parts by that limit, but this results in very invalid HTML (Part 1 has `<div><h2>Title</h2><div>Some conten` and Part 2 has `t</div></div>`), which results mPDF not correctly applying CSS styles to following parts.

mPDF would work fine if a full HTML element was closed before writing, so, the following two parts (for this example) would probably work fine:

`<div><h2>Title</h2>` and `<div>Some content</div></div>`, even if the outer div is not closed.

What would be the best way to get a split method to split a maximum of 100'000 chars per part, but then shorten it so it contains only up to the last HTML closing tag?

Comment: You should know you should include an attempt

Comment: Your saying you need to get back to body tag at the split?

Comment: I think they need to split it between HTML tag elements and each segment of the split needs to be under 100,000 characters.

Comment: @Andreas there would be no advantage of including a standard multibyte split method.
I want to split parts as long as possible, but they must end with a HTML close tag, no matter if it is top level or not. My Idea was to iterate through the last characters until I get a </ sign but this is not the best possibility I guess...

Comment: If any closing HTML tag is the requirement then it sound fairly easy. `$pos = strrpos($str, "</", 100000);` should give you the last position of a start of a closing tag. This number can then be used to search forward with strpos to find the end of tag found. `$pos2 = strpos($str, ">", $pos);`

Comment: Did my code work?

Comment: @Andreas didn‘t try exactly, made an own version which includes some more checks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop and use strrpos and strpos with offset.

```
$len = strlen($str);
$pos2 = 0;
$previous = 0;
While($pos2 < $len){
    $previous = $pos2;
    $pos = strrpos($str, "</", $pos2+100000); 
    $pos2 = strpos($str, ">", $pos);
    $parts[] = substr($str, $previous, $pos2);
}
```

Untested but should do the trick or some slight correction may be needed.

The strrpos finds the start of a closing tag, then I use that position to find the end of the tag.
Use substr to cut from previous position to new closing tag and save it in parts array.
The while loop should end when it finds the last closing tag.
Problem that can occur is if there is text or spaces after the last closing tag. I believe that will make the loop never ending.